How to paste into text Output in Shiny
how can I insert into text Output value from text Input? Problem is because I want insert value from textInput and other text. Functions like paste or glue throws an error.
This code works:

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(  
    textInput("domena", "Podaj domenę"),
    actionButton("act_btn", "Pobierz dane dla domeny"),
    verbatimTextOutput("domena")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {output$domena <- renderText({input$domena})}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

But This throw error
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(  
    textInput("domena", "Podaj domenę"),
    actionButton("act_btn", "Pobierz dane dla domeny"),
    verbatimTextOutput(paste("AAA", domena))
      )
)

server <- function(input, output) {output$domena <- renderText({input$domena})}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


You are trying to concatenate some static text where the value is entered in the textInput section and then display it using verbatimTextOutput. Use the paste() or paste0() functions within the renderText() function.
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(  
    textInput("domena", "Podaj domenę"),
    actionButton("act_btn", "Pobierz dane dla domeny"),
    verbatimTextOutput("concatenated_text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$concatenated_text <- renderText({
    paste("AAA", input$domena)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Thx a lot. Is it possible to use "concatenated_text" in H3 ? tags$h2("text") doesnt works.

@JanJankowskiJanek, you can try using textOutput function to render the text, and then place it within h3 tag. Replace verbatimTextOutput("concatenated_text") with h3(textOutput("concatenated_text"))
